# Django Haystack: Adding custom fields (fl=) to search query string (solr backend)

Tags: python, django, solr, spatial, django-haystack

I am trying to use spatial queries to return a resultset sorted by distance which also has the distance information available for each result.

Getting the distance sorting is easy enough with something like this in my SearchForm:

```
sqs = SearchQuerySet().dwithin('location', self.user_position, D(mi=100)).distance('location', self.user_position).order_by('distance')
```

The haystack docs say that by adding a call to .distance() it will make distance information available in the results (http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/master/spatial.html#id3) however I took the query string it generates from the logs and pass it to solr through a web browser and it doesn't contain the distance information for each document. Taking a look at the build_search_kwargs method for the solr_backend it appears to be unimplemented. Am I missing something, why would it be in the docs if it's not implemented?

All I have to do to the query to get what I want is add '+*dist*:geodist()' to the fl parameter as per the solr docs but I can't find a nice way to do it with haystack. Has anyone done this?

Cheers.